# What does security_policy_version_matches_framework mean?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

When uploading my click app to the store, I get an error in the automated review feedback:

```
1.2 != 1.3 (ubuntu-sdk-15.04) security_policy_version_matches_framework
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As new click frameworks are developed and released, new security policies are required to cover access to newly-introduced features.  The version of the security policy used by your package is defined in the JSON file defined by the `apparmor` hook in your package manifest, and must match the security policy for the version of the framework your package targets.  For example:

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "apackage.adeveloper",
  "maintainer": "adeveloper@example.org",
  "title": "My Package Name",
  "description": "My package description",
  "version": "0.1",
  "architecture": "armhf",
  "framework": "ubuntu-sdk-14.10",
  "hooks": {
    "apackage": {
      "apparmor": "apackage.json",
      "desktop": "apackage.adeveloper.desktop"
    }
  }
}
```

apackage.json:

```js
{
  "policy_groups": [
    "networking"
  ],
  "policy_version": 1.2
}
```

The policy versions to use with each framework are:

`ubuntu-sdk-13.10`: 1.0
`ubuntu-sdk-14.04`: 1.1
`ubuntu-sdk-14.10`: 1.2
`ubuntu-sdk-15.04`: 1.3
`ubuntu-core-15.04`: 15.04